# Custom actions in Contacts app (similar to G+)

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm creating an application that I'd like to integrate with Android's contacts/people application. I set up my custom mime type, a syncadapter, and a contacts.xml file that has a ContactsDataKind element.

This seems to work fine, but it seems it's not possible to define multiple actions per data kind (in this case, I'd like people to be able to view a contact's profile, as well as send them a message directly.

The G+ app seems to handle this, but I've been unable to figure out how they did it. Here's a screenshot of the G+ integration in People: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bj6I.png

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Do you want your app to appear in the menu that comes up from within contacts/people, or to have multiple action choices in your app? On my phone the way I'm able to see a screen like in the screenshot to which you linked is by going into the phone app, touching the menu button (three vertically aligned dots) on the tile of a person there, which brings up a dialog with the person's contact info, then touching on the contact icon in that dialog. At that point I'm not sure whether I'm still in the phone app or the contacts/people app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to **add additional rows in the `ContactsContract.Data` table** when inserting a contact. See "contacts.xml structure" in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html#SocialStream):

> The `<ContactsDataKind>` element controls the display of your
>   application's custom data rows in the contacts application's UI. It
>   has the following syntax:
>
> ```
> <ContactsDataKind
>     android:mimeType="MIMEtype"
>     android:icon="icon_resources"
>     android:summaryColumn="column_name"
>     android:detailColumn="column_name">
> ```

For each one of these, the Contact's app [ContactDetailFragment](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/master/src/com/android/contacts/detail/ContactDetailFragment.java) adds one `DataViewEntry`. The list entries acts as the data for an adapter used to build the contact details UI. When an entry containing an Intent is clicked, `startActivity()` is called. This Intent is built from the data item's MIME type and Uri.

```
entry.intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
entry.intent.setDataAndType(entry.uri, entry.mimetype);
```

---

For example, the G+ app has the following `es_contacts.xml`:

```
<ContactsDataKind android:summaryColumn="data2" android:detailColumn="data3"
```

And creates the rows like this:

```
ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValueBackReference("raw_contact_id", i1)
    .withValue("mimetype", "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.googleplus.profile.comm")
    .withValue("data4", Integer.valueOf(14))
    .withValue("data5", "hangout")
    .withValue("data3", context.getString(R.string.start_hangout_action_label));

ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValueBackReference("raw_contact_id", i1)
    .withValue("mimetype", "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.googleplus.profile")
    .withValue("data4", Integer.valueOf(20))
    .withValue("data5", "addtocircle")
    .withValue("data3", context.getString(R.string.add_to_circle_action_label));
```

Comment: When I used multiple mime types my application appeared multiple times (multiple pages in the slider) in the quick contact popup. Each page had a single action. Is that an issue with my setup, or something I can solve some other way?

Comment: @matiash Where did you find the source for the G+ app?

Comment: @kierans I didn't, just used dex2jar to decompile it.

Comment: What's the mean of `android:summaryColumn="data2" ` and `android:detailColumn="data3"`? And why is not set in the same rows (`data2,3`) and values are set into `data3,4,5`?

Comment: Hi.. I implemented this code and it adds a custom row in contact but when I click on that row it says "No application found to handle this action". Where I need to define action to open my application?